# Displaying an Applet

Tags: java, applet

I made two separate applets for two different animated components. I made one applet with a dark blue background that has stars appearing in random places (using Math.random()), to give the illusion of twinkling. Then I also made an applet of skyscraper windows blinking on and off. I have another applet that just displays the actual skyline (the silhouettes of the buildings, in black), and I'd like to add the stars and windows over the silhouettes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This should not be a problem, especially if both use the same library for a drawing canvas. However, without showing any code, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Not what you want to hear but applets are dead, stop using them. If you want downloadable code look at jnlp

Comment: Yeah. We've all been there. Because of security issues your users will have a tough time using Java applets.  If you are just going to do displays it's time to investigate using HTML5 canvas or other display tools via JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses! This is for a project for my class, which is the very first class in the Java series. We didn't learn anything about Applets in this class, so this project has been done almost entirely on my own. I'll keep working on it, though...

Comment: *"We didn't learn anything about Applets in this class,"* That's a promising sign that the teachers don't want you to waste your time on a dead technology. *"..so this project has been done almost entirely on my own."* Stop wasting your time. For an 'in browser' effect use HTML canvas and JS as suggested by @zipzit. For pure Java, make it a desktop app.